# Setup Raid 10 for backup store

Tags: filesystems, raid10, deduplication

We have HP DL380p Gen8 with Smart Array P420i: 10HDDx6TB, 2 RAID10 6 and 4 HDD, for backup store via Arcserve UDP, deduplication backup configured for 16 KB blocks, we are not satisfied with the speed of recovery, want a better option, how do we need to set up the RAID strip size and format the filesystem block size ?

Comment: You realize that you will lose all data on that raid if you change any of this?

Comment: Of course I understand, that's why two raid arrays are made

Answer (score 2):

Create one big virtual LUN instead of the pools you have. After you’ll do that all the spindles will participate in I/O. Yes, stripe size should match # of spindles or you’ll have stripe interleaved.

Comment: If we make one large LUN from 10 disks,about 25TB,  then in case of failure of one disk we will get a long degradation mode. By spindles, how to find out their number in the disk?               
How important is strip size to random read and rehydration speed when recovering from deduplicated storage. 
Perhaps block size plays a big role in file system formatting?

Comment: Spindle = disk. Just follow 321 backup rule and recover from the second onsite repo if you have an issue with your primary one. https://knowledgebase.starwindsoftware.com/explanation/the-3-2-1-backup-rule/

Comment: @mgkmgk There is only one spindle in a hard drive. It's the cylinder in the middle around which the platters spin. Referring to spindles emphasises the fact that this is rotational media.

Comment: Guys, I'm not asking you about water water, I'm asking about the size of the stripe size, file system and block size in accordance with the deduplication settings, I want high speeds for backups every 15 minutes and instant restores.

Comment: Before picking up the stipe size you need to have properly configured vLUN thing.